# How to select a line of Result Console application

Tags: console-application

I have a Foreach loop:

```
Foreach(htmlnode node in SOMETHING)
{
    var link = node.GetAttributeValue("href", "");
    Console.WriteLine(link);
}
```

that loop shows a list of tags like:

```
http://ca1006761246.trustpass.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
http://ca1006761246.trustpass.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
http://ir100058530.trustpass.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
http://ir100058530.trustpass.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
http://tjyixuan.en.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
http://tjyixuan.en.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
http://alchemyfood.en.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
http://alchemyfood.en.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
http://wuhueasy.en.alibaba.com/contactinfo.html
```

How do I select and store each line separately like:

```
line1:http://ca1006761246.trustpass.alibaba.com/conta
```

How to Focouse on result of consoleApplication Program

Comment: I corrected your formatting. Begging and thanking is not necessary on SO. In your tags include at least what language you are using.

Comment: Looks like a C# Console Application. Am I right? But I don't really see what your question is. You already got the array of URL's, so what more do you want?

Comment: Yes that is C# @JeroenJK ,I want to return Url by single.not all of the urls.how do i configure that foreach insted by  "for" ?